# %post section of rpmbuild not interactive

Tags: compiling, rpm

**Situation:** I'm trying to build a custom rpm to place a config file in a particular location. The installation completes fine by placing config files in proper directories but the %post section is not working. This section echoes user to make an input and 'reads' it. This read value is to be placed in those config files with help of 'sed'.

**Issue:** 'read' is not working in the %post section ie. the installation process does not wait for user to provide input. It basically completes the installation by placing files in the directories. In short, the %post section is not being interactive for user to provide input.

Please see the SPEC file here: http://pastebin.com/5BgkJUpG . This will help to get the idea.

I wrote the exact same lines of %post section above for "postint" section while building a .deb package and it worked fine there. User installing the deb package was able to make the input and this given value was placed in the config file with 'sed'.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a real configuration management tool such as puppet or chef.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Fedora RPM Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html):

**Warning**

Do not try to write interactive scripts. Many users install RPMs automatically. In such cases, or if the user runs a graphical RPM tool, any information your scripts output will be lost. User input will not be available.